# Why can't I set the Resolution field in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I'm new to JIRA as an admin, and I'm wondering why my issues' Resolution field only seems to ever be either "Unresolved" or "Done"?

I suspect this has something to do with the simplified workflow that I chose for my projects? Is the best/right way to fix this adding extra transitions into the workflow?

Ultimately, all I'd really like is a way to mark as issue as cancelled (without actually deleting them). I don't really need to distinguish between invalid or won't fix, or any of that-- comments are fine for those purposes.

If it matters, these projects are all Kanban, and I'm using an agile board with a filter that pulls in multiple projects as my primary interface in JIRA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate the suggested answers from other folks, but ended up going a slightly different route. Here's what I did:

1. Edited all of my workflows to include an additional "Cancelled" status. This was done as statuses seem to work better with the Kanban boards than other options. (I'd initially tried just adding a new "Any --> Done" transition, but wasn't able to, since I already had one.)
2. I set the status' "category" to "Done".
3. In that status, I added a post function to set the issue's Resolution field to "Won't Do" (which was already there, apparently).
4. I added the status to my board's "Done" column.

Now, when dragging issues over to the Done column, I'm offered a choice of two drop targets in that column: Done or Cancelled. Very slick!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question "Why can't I set the Resolution field in JIRA?" :) But anyway, your solution seems nice.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt add any other transition if it is not necessary, jsut for resolution field. 
Go to your admin panel>issues> 
almost at the end of the left menu, shows "Issues' attributes". There you can find "Resolutions" option. You can configure there your different values to resolution field.

** Maybe names of menu, are not exactly as i said you, cause my jira instance is in spanish.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are moving the JIRA's that are Unresolved to a kanban column other than done? If so, then you setup that transition to have a post function to put the resolution status as canceled when you drag it to the column. See this for how to do this:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver070/advanced-workflow-configuration-749383189.html#Advancedworkflowconfiguration-postfunctions

Also, if you would like to change the resolution types for your system, you can do that as well (note: resolution types effect all projects; the entire JIRA system):
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/defining-resolution-field-values-185729576.html

Hope this helps!